# Safe way to save string in JSON from Javascript to MySQL and get it back?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I pass string from JS to the MySQL database via PHP script like this:

JavaScript:

```
var text = getElementById('inputBox').value; //"how are you? ()#@&^""''źćż@**$&#@(~(_(@#$)__0"
var rray = {
   type = "someText";
   message : addslashes(text);
}
var json = JSON.stringify(rray);
```

where:

```
function addslashes(str) {
    str=str.replace(/\\/g,'\\\\');
    str=str.replace(/\'/g,'\\\'');
    str=str.replace(/\"/g,'\\"');
    str=str.replace(/\0/g,'\\0');
    return str;
}
```

And i am sending json to PHP:

```
var result = get_content("http://url.com/script.php?action=" + encodeURIComponent(json) );
```

And saving json to MySQL database (PHP):

```
$data = mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['data']);
$query = "INSERT INTO datas (data) VALUE ('$data')";
execute($query);
```

Next i get it back from database like this:

```
$data = "SELECT DATA from datas WHERE ID = 1";
(...) getting from database
echo $row['DATA'];
```

I get it with Javascript from the PHP:

```
var result = get_content("http://url.com/script.php?get=y"); 
var data = jeval(result);
var action_data = jeval(stripslashes(data.action));
var message = stripslashes(action_data.message);
```

where:

```
function stripslashes(str) {
str=str.replace(/\\'/g,'\'');
str=str.replace(/\\"/g,'"');
str=str.replace(/\\0/g,'\0');
str=str.replace(/\\\\/g,'\\');
return str;
}
```

and:

```
function jeval(str)
{
    lastEvalString = str;
    return eval('(' +  str + ')');
}
```

and display it:

```
getElementById('inputBox').value = message;
```

Most of normal texts are passed to database and back with success. 
But i get strange errors when using signs ( and ) or other special characters like:

```
   unexpected token: )
   illegal token
   script error
```

Could you please look at the code and help me find what i do wrong? 
I can not find it...
Thx.

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: @PLB What preps have in common with this question i don't know

Comment: `$query = "INSERT INTO datas (data) VALUE ('$data')";` I meant this query.

Comment: @PLB Well... i've tried with the same effect...

Comment: it's safe way to do things. I am sure, slashes you add make json formatted strings invalid. Using prepared statements and `htmlspecialchars` you won't need that.

Comment: @PLB I've tried with prepared statements and i have the same effect. Where to use htmlspecialchars?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16543/discussion-between-plb-and-tomaszs)

Comment: @tomaszs I suggest you use stripslashes($_GET['action']) before mysql_escape_string. Then do mysql_escape_string. I had similar scenario, and the data had one too many \s